# Android drawBitmap(...) method is slow?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-canvas, draw

I'm programming an Android game using SurfaceView.

The canvas obtained by the SurfaceView draws an 32bit PNG image of size 80x80 with alpha layer. The time that the method drawBitmap takes is 2-3ms.

Is this normal time for drawing such a small image or there is some implicit conversions happening behind the scene?

I have around 40 game objects (based on sprites) that should be drawn, and the time to draw all of them in one pass takes ~100ms. This is very slow and provides only 10FPS for a dynamic game. I tried many things, like turning off anti-aliasing, turning off the alpha, etc. but to no avail.

How should I go for optimizing the drawing time to get 25FPS at least?

Thanks,
Zlatko

Comment: I may have an answer to suggest if you wouldn't mind posting the code in question.

Comment: Brandon, let me explain the code in a few words: every game object is a class that implements paint method (the game object knows how to draw itself). All of the game objects are hierarchically added to a panel that is, also, a game object with paint method. When the paint method is called for the panel, it iterates through the children (game objects) and calls each game object's paint method consequently. Each game object's drawing takes 2-3ms. Whole panel's drawing takes ~100ms for 40 game objects [I'm sending the Canvas object as a parameter for the paint methods]

Comment: Zlatko, sorry I never responded. Did you find a solution? Based on your description, I was wondering if each object handling the responsibility of painting itself might be the source of the performance hit. Did you try accumulating the pixel values to be drawn in a byte array then drawing the whole screen at once (or something similar)?

Answer (score 1):

I converted all PNG images to 8bit (they were 32bit) and now they are rendering very fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the drawing API to be too slow for your application, you might try to use OpenGL which is supposedly faster. I haven't done blitting-heavy applications myself so I cannot comment on your timing values.

Comment: Thanks, Thalur. I agree OpenGL is faster, but in this case, it's out of game. Do you have any other idea about the canvas?

Comment: Have you tried to do the drawing to an additional canvas created on a bitmap with the same size as the original surface, and only when all objects have been drawn (in memory), drawing this bitmap to the surface using the provided canvas?

Comment: You are talking about double-buffering, right? I obtain the canvas with the call surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null). As far as I know, the canvas I'm getting back is an offline canvas used for drawing. Only after unlockAndPost(canvas), the canvas is dispatched to the hardware. Taking this into consideration, my own double-buffering would only be a duplication of the canvas internal system. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: @Zlatko, are you sure it's the drawBitmap operation that is taking so much time? Usually when drawing without openGL, `surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null)` can take a long time to execute, while drawing bitmaps afterwards should be pretty fast.